# Is it possible to get a work permit in Germany without a degree but with solid contract and 7 years work experience on digital marketing?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, blue-card

I am working in a digital marketing agency in Turkey for almost 7 years and I got a job offer from an agency in Berlin, and I signed the contract.

On 2005 I started studying university and before finishing my university I started working at my present company on 2012. That's why I am still 4th grade on my university, it means my status still seems to be a student.

So my question is; can I get a visa by showing an employment contract + 7 years of work experience + my CV and my transcript (I don't have a degree but I have a transcript).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get a visa in Germany and there is more than one option.

Essentially your application will go from the Ausländerbehörde (foreigners office) to the Agentur für Arbeit (ministry of work) who will approve the visa in the following cases:

1. A shortage of the skill in Germany
2. The employer shows that you posses a special skill that he couldn’t find locally.

Generally one of the conditions is that the salary is above a certain threshold if the job is not in a field in shortage.

The answer is a bit vague and the regulation may have changed. I suggest you look into the blue card which is tied to professions in shortage.

Lastly, keep in mind that while government officials at the Ausländerbehörde may not come across always as the friendliest, the process is quite well outlined and if you fulfil the requirements, you should be able to get a visa easily.